# Problem with vertical align hebrew text (rtl mode) in react native app

Tags: react-native, right-to-left

when we use firstName and lastName without a space - everything is fine
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU5W0.png)

but if you add a space to one of the words, the other word rises up
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JVyz.png)

code
JSX:

```
<View style={styles.nameContainer}>
   <Text style={styles.firstname} numberOfLines={1}>{firstName}</Text>
   <Text style={styles.lastname} numberOfLines={1}>{lastName}</Text>
</View>
```

Styles:

```
nameContainer: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  maxWidth: 176,
  overflow: 'hidden'
},
firstname: {
  fontSize: 16,
  color: Colors.light.text,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  marginEnd: 4
},
lastname: {
  fontSize: 16,
  color: Colors.light.text,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingRight: isRTL ? 0 : 24,
  marginRight: isRTL ? 0 : 8,
  marginBottom: 4,
},
```

can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10712 might help.

Comment: tnx, but this is a bit different, it talks about the difference between android and ios, but I only have a problem with ios, text that has the same styles is displayed at different heights